# OOV (Out Of Vocabulary) word embeddings for Fasttex in low RAM environments

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word-embedding, fasttext

Is there a way to obtain the vectors for OOV (Out Of Vocabulary) words using fasttext but without loading all the embeddings into memory?

I normally work in low RAM environments (<10GB of RAM) so loading a 7GB model into memory is just impossible. To use word embeddings without using that much RAM one can read a `.vec` (which is normally a plain-text) file line by line and store it into a database (which you later access to request a word vector). However to obtain OOV vectors with fasttext you need to use the `.bin` files and load then into memory. Is there a way you can avoid loading the whole `.bin` file?

Comment: A difficult question. Some hints might be here. https://www.quora.com/How-does-fastText-output-a-vector-for-a-word-that-is-not-in-the-pre-trained-model

Comment: Thanks for the link! From the description there I think it's still possible to do it, however I guess a custom implementation must be made (as I've failed to find one that does this). Also, performance will certainly suffer :(

Comment: Not necessarily. The word vectors are created by adding the vectors for the ngrams. So what you see in the vec file is the final vectors, not the individual ngrams. In case you have the ngrams as well then you are in luck.

Comment: Then the question should be: Is there a way to extract all ngrams from the `.bin` file?

Answer (score 0):

What did work for me was to set up a huge swap partition to allow the model to load, then I reduced the size of the vectors from 300 to 100 to make the model fully fit in memory.